# why doesn't a loop show variable re declaration error

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        int j=i;
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    //same thing what a for loop does
/**********************************************/    
    int j=0;
    System.out.println(j);

    int j=1;
    System.out.println(j);
```

I got this silly doubt: I am trying to do the same thing what a for loop does by writing the same statements in a for loop multiple times but after declaring variable `j` for the second time the compiler shows variable redeclaration error but the this error does not show up in a for loop even its trying to execute the same statements multiple times  why?

Comment: because the loop is valid java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the scope of the variable `j` is limited to a single iteration of the loop. Your second code is not entirely equivalent to your first "unrolled" loop. If you would like to make a complete equivalent of it, add curly braces around each simulated iteration, like this:

```
{
    int j=0;
    System.out.println(j);
}
{
    int j=1;
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Now your code will compile and run correctly, producing identical results to the original code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The [basic `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) has the following format

```
BasicForStatement:
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

or, [more simply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html),

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

The *initialization* part executes only once.

> The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed
>   once, as the loop begins.

The variables declared in the *initialization* part are in scope in the entire `for` statement, including its body.

Answer (score -1):

Its because you already declared the variable J, you don't declare it again with int

```
int j=0;
    System.out.println(j);

     j=1;
    System.out.println(j);*
```

Comment: the same thing happen in a for loop right the for loop re declares the variable when its executing for the second time so my question is why doesnt the error show up then?